# Must declare the scalar variable @name al insertar datos desde c# a sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, ssms

tengo una clase con el siguiente código para insertar en la base de datos informacion:

```
public void InsertProducto(int tienda, string nombre, string descripcion, decimal precio)
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.cnnVal("food")))
        {
            List<Producto> producto = new List<Producto>();
            producto.Add (new Producto { ID_tienda = tienda, Nombre_prod = nombre, Descrip_prod = descripcion, Precio_Unit = precio  });
            connection.Execute("dbo.Insert_product @Id_tienda, @Nombre, @Descripcion, @Precio_unit", producto);
        }
    }
```

Y tambien una clase Producto que tiene todos los atributos de producto

```
public class Producto
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ID_tienda { get; set; }
    public string Nombre_prod { get; set; }
    public string Descrip_prod { get; set; }
    public decimal Precio_Unit { get; set; }
    public string Img_origen { get; set; }

    public string fullinfo
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{Nombre_prod} {Descrip_prod} {Precio_Unit}";
        }
    }

}
```

al querer insertar información en mi tabla Producto en sql, me aparece una excepción: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@Nombre".'" y no me permite guardar la información. Provisionalmente la columna imagen la dejé en Null porque no la estoy utilizando. Hice un stored procedure asi:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_product]
@Id_tienda INT,
@Nombre VARCHAR(50),
@Descripcion VARCHAR (100),
@Precio_unit Decimal (6,2)

AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Producto
    (
    ID_tienda,
    Nombre_prod,
    Descrip_Prod,
    Precio_unit
    )
    VALUES
    (
    @Id_tienda,
    @Nombre,
    @Descripcion,
    @Precio_unit
    )
END
GO
```

el ID_producto es IDENTITY así que no lo puse en el stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

El problema te está dando porque los nombres de las propiedades de la clase `Producto` no coinciden con los nombres de los parámetros de entrada del procedimiento almacenado `[dbo].[Insert_product]`.

En tu caso `Producto.Nombre_prod` no es igual a `[dbo].Insert_product].@Nombre` y al ser el primero en no coincidir da el error.

Pero ojo que tampoco coincide `Descrip_prod` con `@Descripcion`.

Por tanto para que estuviera bien debería ser algo así, si cambiaras los nombres de las propiedades de la clase `Producto`:

```
public void InsertProducto(int tienda, string nombre, string descripcion, decimal precio)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.cnnVal("food")))
    {
        List<Producto> producto = new List<Producto>();
        producto.Add (new Producto { ID_tienda = tienda, Nombre = nombre, Descripcion = descripcion, Precio_Unit = precio  });
        connection.Execute("dbo.Insert_product @Id_tienda, @Nombre, @Descripcion, @Precio_unit", producto);
    }
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias por la edición Patricio, queda más elegante y fácil de leer, procuraré hacerlo así a partir de ahora.

Comment: Justo lo hice así anoche. Muchas gracias, errores de principiantes. Espero que a los demás le ayude esto.